# Find matching integer in JSON

Tags: sql, mysql, json

I want to find **`123`** in a JSON string in MySQL.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `reports` 
 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json_data, 123, "$.respCode");
```

When I run this code I get this error

> ```
> Error Code: 3146. Invalid data type for JSON data in argument 1 to 
> function json_contains; a JSON string or JSON type is required.   0.020 sec
> ```

My json in the **`json_data`** column looks like this

```json
{ "bla":"", "bla2":"", "bla3":"", "bla4":"", "respCode":"123", "bla5":"" }
```

i also tried

`WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('json_data', "$.respCode")) = '123'`

but still no luck

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Both question and answers are missing a fiddle which shows the issue (and in case of an answer proves the solution works fine). It would be nice to put more effort in questions and answers on Stackoverflow. Being fast is not as good as being correct.

Comment: Can you post the structure of the `reports` table: SHOW CREATE TABLE `reports`?

Comment: @wchiquito thank for the help. just noticed the reason why it didn't work was the column was set to `longtext` instead of `json`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax of the MySQL [JSON_CONTAINS()](https://www.sqliz.com/mysql-ref/json_contains/) function

```
JSON_CONTAINS(target_json, candidate_json)
JSON_CONTAINS(target_json, candidate_json, path)
```

You can try

```
SELECT * FROM `reports` 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json_data, '{"respCode":"123"}');
```

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tdUxxYsCrhwoD8EXJHXU1A/2)

Comment: i tried this, still getting error. `Error Code: 3141. Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 2.`

Comment: Can you try `SELECT * FROM reports WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json_data, '{"respCode":"123"}',"$");` this

Comment: still getting the same error on this

Comment: @JonasMetzler Understood thank you, but I did tested this query and worked. `function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 2` looks there could be an issue with  2th argument, this is why I side to try the other query.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC Thanks for adding a fiddle link, I think this will help.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC im still getting the same error on mysql workbench. your code does work in the fiddle

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?. Some additional options: see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ikb93rkM).

Comment: @wchiquito it says version 8.0.28

Comment: @wchiquito i tried the fiddle you gave. all gave the same error, but this `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`json_data`, "\"123\"", "$.respCode");` gave an error on `$.respCode` `"." not valid at this position`